# Can I use a laptop fan with a ripped off connector, like this?

Tags: fan, connector

My situation is similar to this, [Is there a way to repair ripped off fan connectors?](https://superuser.com/questions/783015/is-there-a-way-to-repair-ripped-off-fan-connectors), but the yellow and blue wires ripped off, so plugging it in will supply it with power. (Red and black wires are ok.) Can I use my laptop like this? The wires ripped are in italics.

Wires: Black *Yellow* *Blue* Red

Laptop: HP Elitebook 8440p

Comment: More detail is needed.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I added wiring and laptop model.

Answer (score 2):

You can... But without the other two wires you will lose the computer's ability to:

**Read the live RPM of the fan**.
**PWM control of the fan.**.

So the computer will lose the ability to adjust the fan speed to real-time temperature. Most 4 pin fans I have messed with in electronics project's will be 100% RPM if the PWM control pin is disabled.

Your best bet is to just replace the fan. The other option (not recommended) If you are savy with a soldering iron, and have decent vision you can remove the metal pins from the plastic connector with a baby pin. They have a barb sticking up from each pin that holds it into the connector that can be released with the baby pin, strip the wires, resolder, and lock them back in the connector.

IMHO that method really isn't worth your time, and isn't easy to do. Just replace the fan, you should be able to find one (depending on model) for $10~30 usd.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dusting off your soldering iron or purchasing a new plug, as the first answer to the other question suggests.

At the moment it would still get power but you need all the wires to regulate the fan speed, so it is up to you what sort of performance you need.

Good luck with it

Comment: Those connectors are not really solderable, they're push-fit & clamp/squeeze. I suppose you could if you tried hard, but you'd probably just melt the plug. Probably not worth the effort, just buy a new one.

Comment: @tetsujin, they are... The pins release from those connectors. The question for that really comes down to: what's your time worth to you?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - hmm, yup, you can pop them out if you have the gear. Weeny flathead screwdriver, needle-nose pliers, soldering station with stand-clamps & magnifying-glass… My time would only be worth even that effort if the plug was otherwise irreplaceable, though tbh I wouldn't have broken it in the first place ;))